# What is the polymer elements used in first page of the polymer-project 1.0?

Tags: responsive-design, polymer

I would like to build an page with similar behavior the first page of the polymer-project 1.0.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/

It is resposive!

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am using

```
<paper-header-panel> and <paper-toolbar>
```

, but I did not find this behavior.

I do not want the left drawer, like it´s suggested in Polymer Started Kit.

How could I get this behavior (first page of the Polymer Project) just with polymer elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They are using media queries in their code to show and hide the toolbars.

See it in https://www.polymer-project.org/css/homepage.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    #dropdown-toggle {
        display:inline-block
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, understand! But I would like to find components (iron- paper-?) ready to use with this behavior. Similar to bootstrap.

Comment: You could make your own.